# Google Maps address search crashing when edit text is empty

Tags: android, google-maps, null, android-edittext, try-catch

Hi I have made an o'clock method inside of my application which searches for a address depending on what the user has entered into the edit text. This works perfectly fine but crashes when I press the search button when the edit text is empty. Could any spot what I could be doing wrong and how I could possibly solve the situation.

```
public void onSearch(View view) {

    EditText findLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = findLocation.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;


    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {


        //Geocode gecoder = new Geocoder(this)
        //geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        //then add try and catch


        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {


            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


            //after try and catch
            // List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


        } catch (IOException e) {









            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

    Address address = addressList.get(0);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location.toString()));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


}
```

Stack trace

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.example.hadleigh.googlemapstest.MapsActivity.onSearch(MapsActivity.java:91)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

Comment: Please add stack trace from the crash from logcat.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You had the right logic to check if your `EditText` was empty, but you are still expecting to have your `addressList` filled with results. You need to put the `addMarker` logic inside the `try-catch blocks`, or check if the addressList is not empty:

```
if (addressList != null && !addressList.isEmpty()) {
    Address address = addressList.get(0);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location.toString()));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onSearch(View view) {

    EditText findLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = findLocation.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;


    if (location.isEmpty()) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;


    }else {

        //Geocode gecoder = new Geocoder(this)
        //geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        //then add try and catch


        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {


            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


            //after try and catch
            // List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


        } catch (IOException e) {









            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

    Address address = addressList.get(0);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location.toString()));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));


    return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem with your initial code was it should have been && rather than ||  , but isEmpty() like you have here is better :)

Comment: Thanks, it was pain to figure out but its finally done :D